# Open-source trouble ticket system

Tags: looking-for-a-script, customer-service, ticket-system

I would like to centralize the support of my many sites. I'm looking for a open source trouble ticket system which:

1) I can host it myself or it can be hosted by a third party (think Wordpress)

2) It has email aliases, so the real email addresses will not be disclosed to the support person

Which system would you suggest me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think OSticket is what your are looking for
http://osticket.com/

Screenshots via http://osticket.com/tour/

I'm using it for 2 different websites on the same installation we their own premade replies and identities.

Answer (score 3):

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) is a very flexible project management system with issue tracking. I have several instances, created for different companies, and I'm very happy with it.

It supports multi projects, it's easy to use and configurable. You can install it on your server.

There's also a fork called [Chiliproject](https://www.chiliproject.org/).